# JQuery UI dialog with destroy option and return to initial state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a trouble with JQuery Dialog.

I have this code : (initially is a simple DIV before clicking on second button called Maximize)

http://pastebin.com/BnpZ1AMA

After clicking "Maximize", the visible div becomes dialog.
But when I want to return to div (initial state),it doesn't appear anymore on screen. In documentation,there say "Remove the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state."

I have javascript code :

```
           function makeit(data,maximize,minimize)
            {
                $(data).dialog();
                $(maximize).hide();
                $(minimize).show();
            }

            function remakeit(data,maximize,minimize)
            {
                $(data).dialog("destroy");
                $(maximize).show();
                $(minimize).hide();
            }
```

Is "destroy" good option or what need I to change back to DIV element ?

Thank you

Comment: better reformat your source code there to make it readable...

Comment: I insert pastebin link,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that after you call *dialog.destroy()*, jQuery UI does return the element to its pre-init state, but makes it so that it has *display:none* set.

so:

```
remakeit = function(data,maximize,minimize)
            {
                $(maximize).show();
                $(minimize).hide();
                $(data).dialog("destroy");
                $(data).show();

            }
```

---

I think the problems you are having are due to the fact that the designers of jquery UI meant for the dialog div to act as a dialog div, not play both parts - a dialog div and a regular DOM div.

So, you have two options:

1) Continue the way you have been doing so far (trying to use the same div both as a dialog div and as a regular DOM div) - in that case, you have to play by what jquery UI does. If you say that when it "returns the div to its pre-init state" it is attached to the end of the body (as a "footer"), then in your *remakeit* function after the *$(data).show();* statement, add a statement for moving the div to its original place:

```
remakeit = function(data,maximize,minimize)
            {
                $(maximize).show();
                $(minimize).hide();
                $(data).dialog("destroy");
                $(data).appendTo("#originalDialogContainer");
                $(data).show();
            }
```

Where *#originalDialogContainer"* is a div that originally contains your div:

```
<div id="originalDialogContainer">
    <div class="theory">
          ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link that explains moving DOM elements around in jQuery
http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/

2) Have 2 "theory" divs to begin with - one will be for showing the "theory" div when it is "minimized", and one will be "theoryDialog" for showing the theory div as a dialog. When the user clicks "maximize" you will hide the regular "theory" div and do *$(".theoryDiv").dialog();*, and when the user clicks "minimize" inside the dialog you will destroy\close the dialog and show the regular "theory" div.

Hope this helps...

Comment: and by the way you can use jsfiddle.net for html\javascript code - http://jsfiddle.net/6NdbA/3/

Comment: the DIV appear as footer (under of all other div) but I wish to appear where he was.

Comment: unfortunately,appendTo it didn't append to my parent div. Your second advice was my first intention. but my PHP file is too long and I wish to minimize codes (including javascript).

Comment: If stil relevant - How come appendTo() didn't work? Does the function throw an exception? Maybe you can supply your entire code, the little code I tried to run worked okay...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a minimize/maximize experience like windows, try my approach here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561470/335514

and fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/ZSk6L/