# How to Minimize/Maximize  jQuery Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, video-streaming, jquery-dialog

I am using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/dialog/)  to show a video. The video is working fine.

What I want to do is minimize the Dialog-element just like in an OS or something like that. A small icon like (" - ") that would minimize my dialog and when I press (*) it would close the dialog but keep the video running in the background.

Here's my code

```
//Watch Video

$(".watchVideo").live('click',function(){
    if($('div.ui-dialog').length){
        $('div.ui-dialog').remove();
    }

    var path  = $(this).attr('rel');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');

    var $dialog = $('<div>', {
        title: translator['Watch Video']
    }).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 500
    });

    var tab = '<table  style="margin: 10px 10%;"><tr><td><object id="MediaPlayer1" width="500" height="400" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" align="middle"><param name="'+title+'" value="'+path+'"> <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="True">  <param name="DefaultFrame" value="mainFrame"> <param name="autostart" value="false">  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"  pluginspage = "http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"  src="'+path+'"   autostart="false"  align="middle" width="500"    height="300"   defaultframe="rightFrame"  showstatusbar="true"> </embed></object></td></tr></table>';

    $('<div id="updateContent">').html(tab).appendTo($dialog);
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;

});
```

where  var tab is equal to

```
<object id="MediaPlayer1" width="500" height="400"
classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..."
type="application/x-oleobject" align="middle">
    <param name="FileName" value="YourFilesName.mpeg">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="True">
    <param name="DefaultFrame" value="mainFrame">
    <param name="autostart" value="false">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
     pluginspage = "http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
     src="YourFilesName.mpeg"
     autostart="false"
     align="middle"
     width="500"
    height="300"
    defaultframe="rightFrame"
    showstatusbar="true">
 </embed>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is an extension for jQuery UI dialog, named "DialogExtend" that allows you to add a maximize, minimize and restore buttons:

- Code: https://github.com/ROMB/jquery-dialogextend
- Demo: http://jsbin.com/ehagoy/154

Works perfectly.

Comment: Icons are messed up using latest jquery-ui

Comment: Old question and answer, but wondering if there is support for something like this with mobile browsers, this extension doesn't work very well on mobile.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of approaches that you could try.

1. Introduce a new minimize button and append it to the `ui-dialog-titlebar` and on click change the dialog to a `position: fixed` and position it so only the title bar is visible on the bottom of the screen.
2. Fairly similar approach - change your original dialog div's height to 0. Allow the dialog to be draggable, so a user can move it around. but you would probably need to offset the dialog to the bottom of the viewport. This approach leaves the `ui-dialog-titlebar` intact - you could also change the width of the dialog on the fly, to make the minimize effect.
3. Use `.animate` or other transitions (or easing, such as easeInExpo - http://ralphwhitbeck.com/demos/jqueryui/effects/easing/)

But the easiest approach that uses some of the methods above is:

What you need for the effect is to change is:

- width of the window
- height of the window
- top position
- left position

like this:

```
    $('#window').dialog({
    draggable: false,
    height: 200,
    buttons: [
    {
        text: "minimize",
        click: function() {
            $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').animate({
                height: '40px',
                top: $(window).height() - 40
            }, 200);            
        }
    }]


});

$('#open').click(function() {
   $('#window').parents('.ui-dialog').animate({
       //set the positioning to center the dialog - 200 is equal to height of dialog
       top: ($(window).height()-200)/2,
       //set the height again
       height: 200
            }, 200); 
});
```

What this does it set the height of the dialog to `0`, and positions it at the bottom of the viewport. On maximise, it recalculates the center position, gives the dialog a height, and animates it back into view.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/ZSk6L/

**Updated fiddle with minimize/maximize.**

Comment: @ Jason hmmm this is good.but what if i want Maximize it again coz once minimize its disappear in jsfiddle(demo)

Answer (score 2):

I made a little plugin with the widget factory that extends the jquery ui dialog.

I use the jquery widget factory to add new functionnalities

```
$.widget('fq-ui.extendeddialog', $.ui.dialog, {
...
})(jQuery);
```

In the Jquery UI dialog code, there is a _createTitlebar method. 
I override it and add a maximize and minimize button

```
_createTitlebar: function () {
    this._super();
    // Add the new buttons
    ...        
    },
```

- [jquery-extendeddialog](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/jquery-extendeddialog)
- [sample page](http://crazytuna.github.io/jquery-extendeddialog/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery DialogExtend plugin.
It offer dialog maximize, minimize, and collapse features.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DialogExtend plugin solves the problem though when using an iframe it keeps refreshing  the iframe's content.